# Use jQuery to change nested text

Tags: jquery, replace

```
<div class="registrationField BIRTH_DATE">
 <span class="registrationlabel BIRTH_DATE">
  <label for="registrationTextField_3">Birth Date (M/D/YY)</label>:
  <span class="registration_requiredCue">*</span>
 </span>
 <input class="registrationInput registrationTextField BIRTH_DATE" id="registrationTextField_3" type="text"></div>
```

I want to change the text of the label (in this case 'Birth Date (M/D/YY)') however since the label is does not have a class or ID I can't quite figure out how to do so. Unfortunately I don't have access to the HTML portion of this form, so I need to rely on jQuery to change the label. I've tried over a dozen methods (most from similar questions on this site). The best I've been able to do is hook into the out span, but because of how the form is generated I can't guarantee that the label will be the same each time so I can't just replace that.

My current iteration doesn't work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".registrationlabel.BIRTH_DATE").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3;}).find("Birth").replaceWith("Death");});
```

Comment: `find('Birth')` is not valid.  `Birth` is not a valid selector string.

Comment: Why not just update the entire `label[for="registrationTextField_3"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector here to find any `label` with text `Birth Date` and then using jquery [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method replace text "Birth" with "Death" like:

```js
$(".registrationlabel.BIRTH_DATE label:contains('Birth Date')")
  .text((i, v) => v.replace("Birth", "Death"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="registrationField BIRTH_DATE">
 <span class="registrationlabel BIRTH_DATE">
  <label for="registrationTextField_3">Birth Date (M/D/YY)</label>:
  <span class="registration_requiredCue">*</span>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the label by its `for` attribute:

```
 $("label[for='registrationTextField_3']").text("New Text");
```